# Vibrate the device in the Sensor mode

Tags: android, sensors

I have implemented the Sensor functionality in my app.Now after 2 mins vibration is in activate mode due to which the device get some movement and sensor get work.What i want that the sensor get active only when the user manually move the device.There should be no effect of vibration on the sensor.Following is my code.Thanks for Advance...

```
vib= (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

vib.vibrate(val);

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x=event.values[0];
        float y=event.values[1];
        float z=event.values[2];


        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);

        if(deltaX>NOISE){
            compareX();
        }
        else if(deltaY>NOISE){
            compareX();
        }
        else if(deltaZ>NOISE){

            compareX();
        }

        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
    }
}

private void compareX() {
    mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    vib.cancel();
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmService.class));
    System.out.println("Movemenet>><><><><><><>><Occur");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm reading that correctly, you want to turn on the accelerometer but not get changes in it due to vibration of the device-  filter it out somehow.  That really wouldn't be possible.  The framework has no method to do it, and any attempt to do so would be difficult-  the vibrator's strength will vary from device to device, and even between calls in the same device.  And they don't really calibrate those things-  there's really no way to do that accurately.

Comment: Yeah you are right..It should be vary from device to device.I have getting this problem only in Samsung Galaxy S3.In other devices there is no effect of vibration on the Sensor.Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please Gabe try to help me to sort out this issue..Due to it my app is not delivered to the client... :(

Comment: I'd suggest measuring how fast it vibrates and doing some digital signal processing-  use a bandgap filter to allow through everything but that range of values.